# IONIC 3 Property '..' does not exist on type 'TheMovieDbApiConfigImage[]'

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I encounter a problem, for info I manage to retrieve the values and display on the HTML part, but I would like to retrieve these values in the typescript part to create a URL and save it in a variable, in **"Prez.ts"**.
Here is my concatenation :

urlJaquette: string = this.configMovie.images.**secure_base_url** + this.configMovie.images.**backdrop_sizes[0]** + this.choiceMovie.poster_path;

I have an error on words that are after *"this.configMovie.images."*,The bold parts in the concatenation have the error. This error message is **"Property 'the word after this.configMovie.images.' does not exist on type 'TheMovieDbApiConfigImage []' "**

[image: error]

**Provider : ThemoviedbServicesProvider**

```
// Core companents

import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

// RxJS

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

// Models //
import {TheMovieDbApiSearch} from '../models/search/themoviedbapi-search-model';
import {TheMovieDbApiConfig} from '../models/config/themoviedbapi-config-model';
import {TheMovieDbApiDescription} from '../models/description/themoviedbapi-desciption-model';

/*
  Generated class for the ThemoviesdbServicesProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/

@Injectable()
export class TheMoviedbServicesProvider {

  private baseUrl: string = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/';
  private apiConf : string = 'configuration?api_key=';
  private apiSearch : string = 'search/movie?api_key=';

  private apiKey: string = 'apiKey';

    constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  public getConfig(): Promise<TheMovieDbApiConfig> {

    const url = `${this.baseUrl}${this.apiConf}${this.apiKey}`;

    return this.http.get(url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json() as TheMovieDbApiConfig)
    .catch(error => console.log('Une erreur est survenue : ') + error)

  }

  public getMovies(arg, arg1, arg2, arg3): Promise<TheMovieDbApiSearch> {

    const url = `${this.baseUrl}${this.apiSearch}${this.apiKey}&language=${arg}&query=${arg1}&page=${arg2}&include_adult=${arg3}`;

    return this.http.get(url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json() as TheMovieDbApiSearch)
    .catch(error => console.log('Une erreur est survenue : ') + error)

  }

  public getChoice(arg, arg1): Promise<TheMovieDbApiDescription> {

    const url = `${this.baseUrl}movie/${arg}?api_key=${this.apiKey}&language=${arg1}`;

    return this.http.get(url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json() as TheMovieDbApiDescription)
    .catch(error => console.log('Une erreur est survenue : ') + error)

  }


}
```

**Prez.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

// Providers //
import {ThemoviedbServicesProvider} from '../../providers/themoviedb-services';

// Models //
import {TheMovieDbApiConfig} from '../../models/config/themoviedbapi-config-model';
import {TheMovieDbApiDescription} from '../../models/description/themoviedbapi-desciption-model';

/**
 * Generated class for the PrezPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage({
    defaultHistory: ['FilmPage']
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-prez',
  templateUrl: 'prez.html',
})
export class PrezPage {

    configMovie : TheMovieDbApiConfig = new TheMovieDbApiConfig();
    choiceMovie : TheMovieDbApiDescription = new TheMovieDbApiDescription();
    id: number;
    langue: string;
    urlJaquette: string = this.configMovie.images.secure_base_url + this.configMovie.images.backdrop_sizes[0] + this.choiceMovie.poster_path;
    manuJaquette: string;
    textValue: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private themoviedbServicesProvider: ThemoviedbServicesProvider) {
    this.ionViewDidLoad();
    this.id = this.navParams.get('id');
      this.langue = this.navParams.get('langue');
    console.log(this.id);

    this.resultGetChoice(this.id, this.langue);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.themoviedbServicesProvider.getConfig()
        .then(configMovieFetched => {
        this.configMovie = configMovieFetched;
    })

  }

  resultGetChoice(arg, arg1) {
      this.themoviedbServicesProvider.getChoice(arg, arg1)
        .then(choiceMovieFetched => {
                this.choiceMovie = choiceMovieFetched;
                console.log(this.choiceMovie);
            })
  }

}
```

here is the code in the models

```
import {TheMovieDbApiConfigImage} from './themoviedbapi-config-image-model';
import {TheMovieDbApiChangeKeys} from './themoviedbapi-config-change-key-model';

export class TheMovieDbApiConfig {
    change_keys: TheMovieDbApiChangeKeys[];
    images: TheMovieDbApiConfigImage[];
}
```

and

```
import  {BackdropSizes} from './backdropsizes';
import  {LogoSizes} from './logosizes';
import  {PosteSizes} from './postesizes';
import  {ProfileSizes} from './profilesizes';
import  {StillSizes} from './stillsizes';

export class TheMovieDbApiConfigImage {
    backdrop_sizes: BackdropSizes[];
    base_url: string;
    logo_sizes: LogoSizes[];    
    poster_sizes: PosteSizes[];
    profile_sizes: ProfileSizes[];
    secure_base_url: string;
    still_sizes: StillSizes[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

images is an array of type TheMovieDbApiConfigImage. In order to call secure_base_url and backdrop_sizes[0] you will need to reference an index of the array like so

```
this.urlJaquette = this.configMovie.images[0].secure_base_url + this.configMovie.images[0].backdrop_sizes[0] + this.choiceMovie.poster_path
```

once you put in a index for this.configMovie.images you will have access to both variables.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.
I did what you said and I have this error now
**"Runtime Error Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Can not read property '0' of undefined
TypeError: Can not read property '0' of undefined
     at PrezPage.webpackJsonp.281.PrezPage.resultGetChoice "**

Comment: Did you make a change in either resultGetChoice or getChoice? if so can you post the changes you made?

Comment: Hello, So I was wrong in the error message. The message is -> **"Runtime Error Uncaught (in promised): TypeError: Can not read property '0' of undefined
TypeError: Can not read property '0' of undefined
     at new PrezPage "** I did not change my code I did a paste copy of the code you posted above.

Comment: So you wont necessarily be able to just copy and paste what i put. You need to use the correct index of the array to make sure you are getting valid data. You will need to either put the correct index or you will need to iterate over the array to find the correct index you want. If you don't want/need to use an array then i suggest changing images to just TheMovieDbApiConfigImage instead of TheMovieDbApiConfigImage[]

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem comes from !! This comes from the Life Cycle Sequence,  the variable

```
this.urlJaquette = this.configMovie['images']['secure_base_url'] + this.configMovie['images']['backdrop_sizes'][0] + this.choiceMovie['poster_path']
```

is executed before receiving the information, for that I added a button attached to a function with a

```
console.log (this.configMovie['images'] ['secure_base_url'] + this.configMovie['images']['backdrop_sizes'][0] + this.choiceMovie['poster_path'])
```

And here I received the variable concatenated in my console !!

Now I have to find the right sequence, but I did not find what to do, I tried [lifecycle-events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events) described in the ionic doc and the [lifecycle-hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) described in the angular doc. Do you have an idea ?